# Есть ли стандартная фича в Python такому коду?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Часто приходится один и тот же код писать. Задался собственно вопросом: есть ли стандартаня фича этому коду? А то постоянно его писать приходится...

```
if key in dict_test:
    dict_test[key].append(val)
else:
    dict_test[key] = [val]
```

P.S.: Шапками не кидайте, типа напиши функцию и вызывай ее...

Просто хочу узнать есть ли уже велосипед? Ну или аналог этого велосипеда.. =)

Comment: dict_test.setdefault(key, [])

Comment: `dict_test.setdefault(key, []).append(val)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict_test = defaultdict( lambda: [] ) # тот-же dict, но для несуществующих ключей,  значение будет создаваться автоматом, при первом обращении.

dict_test[key].append("val") # здесь никаких if-ов. списки создаются автоматически.
```

Comment: Вместо `lambda: []` обычно пишут просто list.